# Is there another way to assign PHP variables that I don't know about?

Tags: php, smarty, variable-assignment

I'm debugging some client PHP code that has me stumped. As this pseudo-example illustrates, there is code on the receiving end of a form submission that processes the form values, but without ever apparently assigning those values:

(On form submission, where form has fields 'name' and 'position'):

```
echo "The name is = ". $name;
echo "The position is = ". $position;
```

This code is part of a large app, and code from other files is called before this. BUT the crucial point is that if I do a search for '$name = ' across the entire codebase it never shows up. How then is it possible that the request variable gets assigned to `$name`? Is there another way to assign value to a variable in PHP *other* than `$var = value`??

My only other clue is that this project uses Smarty, which I don't know anything about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may be that the person that created the code was working on a server with [register_globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) on. What that does, for example, is create regular global variables as the result of a form submission rather than populating the $_POST or $_GET arrays.

Comment: THANK YOU itsmequinn, Jasmo, and JacobM- I just got educated

Answer (score 5):

If the [register_globals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) directive has been set to true in php.ini, then all POST attributes will also show up as individual variables, in the way you describe.  Note that this directive is false by default, and that use of this directive is deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

When you look at the [smarty documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.variables.tpl#language.assigned.variables) you can see that variables are assigned like this (copied from the linked page):

```
<?php

$smarty = new Smarty();

$smarty->assign('firstname', 'Doug');
$smarty->assign('lastname', 'Evans');
$smarty->assign('meetingPlace', 'New York');

$smarty->display('index.tpl');

?>
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning Smarty (even if perhaps not correctly); however, doesn't this only affect the variables available in the `tpl` template file?

Comment: I am not sure, I never really used smarty, but I figured it uses some method to assign variables to the view like this `assign()`. I just wanted to give a hint as to what else to look for in the code

Comment: @Yarin No, assigning the variables should happen in your .php-file, (the controller passing the data to the view). In the .tpl-file you access these variables like this: `Hello {$firstname} {$lastname}, glad to see you can make it.` (again taken from the documentation)

Comment: Roger that- this wasn't the culprit in the end, but good to know.

Answer (score 3):

Technically yes there is.

```
$x = 'name';
$$x = 'harry';
echo 'Yer a wizard '.$name;
```

(I would be surprised if this was the reason)

Comment: But a quick search of 'position' in all the source code pages should show evidence of this happening. 'name' might be too common to search for, but search for 'position' and see what comes up. Let us know if this is what happened!

Answer (score 2):

I guess your server has register_globals setting on, which automatically generates variables from posted items:

```
$_POST['foo'] === $foo
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is another outbreak of the [`register_globals`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) disease?

This has been thought to have died out, but surfaces again and again!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like someone included those variables with the intention of doing more with them, but never got around to doing so. Unless an include php page is assigning values to those variables, nothing will go in them.

Answer (score 1):

Try turning your error reporting level up, if these variables are being used but haven't been initialised, a warning will be shown